# JHipster - Entity with JDL, Java entity class with unexpected @Column annotation

Tags: jhipster

I tried creating a JHipster app with one of the options: --skip-client.
Also I disabled Liquibase afterwards.

Then I created a test entry, similar to:

```
entity Test {
    id String,
    hireDate ZonedDateTime
}
```

I put this into a test.jh file, executed on a terminal: 
jhipster import-jdl test.jh

When I looked into the Java source of the app, I discovered a Test.java class, id was automatically recognized as a primary key I believe:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;
```

But hireDate was annotated with:

```
@Column(name = "hire_date")
private ZonedDateTime hireDate;
```

Why is that?

I created a view "Test" for this entity in my database, also the columns are "Id" and "HireDate".

But with the automaticaly added @Column annotation, the column name for example "hire_date" doesn't exist in my view.

Can I solve this somehow? I this something related to JHipster generator or to do with Spring Boot?

And there is another issue:

```
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "jhi_type", length = 100)
private String type;
```

To name a Java field "type" seems ok, but JHipster makes "jhi_type" for @Column

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the JHipster naming conventions: snake-case for columns and camel-case for java entity fields. If you had used Liquibase, this would have worked fine.

You can't configure this behavior in the generator.

Disabling liquibase does not change the fact that you created a view in your database that does not respect JHipster naming conventions. JHipster generates code that expects columns to be named this way. Either you respect these conventions or you modify the generated code manually.

Alternatively, you could try [jhispter-db-helper module](https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper) but it seems this project has been abandoned.

Comment: Not quite sure if I understand: When I execute jhipster import-jdl <JDL file>, it tries to use Liquibase? If Liquibase is not disabled (I added to application.yml include: no-liquibase to disable it), then the field names in the entity Java class would be the same like defined in JDL (hireDate), but also in the @Column annotation (hiredDate)? Because I disabled Liquibase, jhipster import-jdl can't use Liquibase and therefore uses the JHipster naming conventions, as you discribed?

Answer (score 2):

No need to define the id field in the jdl, you get it for free by default.